# Strange 404/j_security_check error with Websphere 6.1

Tags: websphere, rad, j-security-check

I have a websphere 6.1 configuration and the application is running, but some requests go to j_security_check but the last one (there are filters associated with J_security_check) will generate a 404 error.

For example:

(1) User posts to:
http://localhost:9081/Page/j_security_check
And it works on Filter1,
but later requests to Filter2 get a 404 error.

(1a) Note, the following filters are associated with j_security_check:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

(2)
The code reaches the filter code:

chain.doFilter(req, res);

WASReqURL has the following cookie value, this is needed by j_security_check:
http://localhost:9081/Test/test.html

Ideally, the client should end up on 'http://localhost:9081/Test/test.html'

But, I get a 404 error at a subsequent request to j_security_check:
http://localhost:9081/Page/j_security_check

Also, here is relevant snippet in the web.xml file.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Go</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/Go</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

---

The question is, what controls 'J_security_check' from the websphere perspective.

Details:
RAD7
Websphere Server 6.1, local box

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is the subsequent request a second one from a authenticated user, a second one from non-authenticated, or a forwarded request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Application servers > server1 > Web container > Custom Properties* and make sure the `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility` variable is set to true. This variable serves as the `j_security_check` switch for the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very well known issue with WebSphere 6.1 and Spring Security.

You need to add this variable to the server properties using the admin console:

```
    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility = true
```

also i remember you need to install some patch for websphere, depending on the exact version.

Just look in internet about the variable I mention and you will find the solution...

Hope it helps ...

Miguel